# Is there a way to enable coasting or inertial scrolling on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: browser, scrolling

I'm on a desktop using a mouse and on windows I enjoy inertial scrolling the MS Edge provides by default. However that's not the case for Edge on linux, or any of the chromium browsers. Firefox is even worse as it is capped for some reason to only 60fps. With chromium based browsers, smooth scrolling, threaded scrolling and HW acceleration enabled, I'm still not able to configure inertial scrolling. Is it even possible? Using Nvidia drivers.